# jQuery deferred.fail() only executes once

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

Below jQuery's deferred `fail()` only executes once, why?

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();

$('button').on('click', function(){

    if(typeof lorem === 'undefined') {
        return dfd.reject();
    }
});

dfd.fail(function(){
    alert('Variable lorem is not defined');
});
```

https://codepen.io/bartclaeys/pen/EOooKy

Expected behavior: When you click the button repeatably, the alert should fire repeatedly.

Comment: So it does exactly what it's supposed to do? [promises cannot be resolved or rejected more than once.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)

Comment: @KevinB I want it to fire multiple times, so I guess I need to reset the promise somehow?

Comment: You need something other than a promise. Not a promise. such as an event. or simply a function.

Comment: Just define the deferred within the click event and have the fail handler as a global function, or within the click also, that's up to you

Comment: @DavidEspino Trying, not working...

Comment: Replace your `return` line with `alert('Variable lorem is not defined');`. Either your example WAY oversimplifies your problem, or you are way over complicating it with your solution to said problem.

Comment: @KevinB Basically not using deferred at all?

Comment: Yes, deferred (aka promises) are the wrong tool for this job.

Comment: @KevinB Care to explain why? My code isn't as simple as above, various vars are being checked whether they are available.

Comment: If you need the reject to happen more than once, it's the wrong tool. plain and simple. You can't reset it. You can replace it with a new promise, but then you've got to rebind all the callbacks too... which is pointless. just use a function.

Comment: @KevinB Bizarre, like a click on a button executing an AJAX call can only be rejected once...

Comment: Well, yes, but each click would be generating a new promise, one per ajax call. That's entirely different from what you showed in your question.

Comment: @KevinB See my answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question, below works:

```
$('button').on('click', function(){

    var dfd = $.Deferred();

    dfd.fail(function(){
        alert('Error');
    });

    if(typeof lorem === 'undefined') {
        return dfd.reject();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's  exactly what I suggested -.-